# How to display an image in the column on clicking a button in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am having a ng-grid that has a column which shows images based on values, my filter for images is

```
app.filter('imagefilter', function() {

return function(S) 
{

if(S==="Severe") { return 'Major.gif'; }

if(S==="High") { return 'Major.gif'; }

if(S==="Low") { return 'Normal.gif'; }

if(S==="Moderate") { return 'Retrieving.gif'; }

if(S==="Critical") { return 'Warning.gif'; }

if(S==="High") { return 'SiteUnmanaged.gif'; }

return 'unknown';

};


})
```

Now i need a column consisting on buttons, clicking on which it should change the previous column image to some other image. Can anyone pls help me out.Thanks already.

Comment: I have no idea frhd to do it, i am new to angular. What i know is I need a function that wil change the value of S to some image. and $scope.expbutton = '<button id="editBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="(Name of the function)" >Edit</button> '; this template can be used to add a button in one column